# Unable to authenticate vsFTPd virtual user wih SSH/SFTP Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, vsftpd

I'm somewhat new to linux so forgive me if the answer is an obvious one. I've been trying for days now without success. I'm setting up a simple SFTP service with vsFTPd. I've had no issues setting up a virtual user account over FTP or a real user over SFTP but as soon as I try to combine a virtual user with SFTP I run into an authentication problem.

I'm following [THIS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd) basic guide.

By adding These lines to a working Virtual User / FTP setup in the config file...

```
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
```

I get the following error from filezilla over a local netowrk:

```
Connecting to ***.***.**.**...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "vpolyuser@***.***.**.**" 22
Command:    Pass: *******
Error:  Authentication failed.
Error:  Critical error
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I am assuming that my SSH server does not recognize the virtual users I setup following the guide above. Is there a way to make this happen? Also I want the virtual users to remain jailed.

Answer (score 0):

SFTP does not require vsftpd to be installed. As long as SSH is working, you might as well just login using the credentials of SSH.

FTPS and FTPES are the the SSL-encrypted connections of vsftpd.

Comment: I see... Is there a way to jail an SSH user? My SSH users have access to brows the whole server.

Comment: There is a question regarding jailing SSH users and it is on askubuntu (http://askubuntu.com/questions/93411/simple-easy-way-to-jail-users)... As for vsftpd, it is in the section 3 of the instructional tutorial you are following. :)